# How can I parse the localStorage object and get values

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have below `localStorageData` object with following items. Depending upon the need I might pass any object like `recordId`, `autoId`, `simId`, `sessionId` into the  `localData.saveLocalStorageData({recordId});`

So in the main.js file how can I call the `localStorageData` object and parse the `recordId` or `autoId` or `simId` and assign the value to `data` ?

**localStorage.js**

```js
    let localStorageData = {};
    
    function saveLocalStorageData ({recordId, autoId, simId, sessionId}) {
        localStorageData = {
            recordId:recordId,
            autoId: autoId,
            simId: simId,
            sessionId : sessionId
        }
        return localStorageData
    }
    
    export { saveLocalStorageData };
```

**record.js**

```js
        let localData = require("../../support/localStorage");

        let text =  $('#someId > span').text();
        let ele = text.split("#");
        let recordId = {};
        recordId = ele;
        const localStorageData =   localData.saveLocalStorageData({recordId});
        window.localStorage.setItem('localStorageData', JSON.stringify(localStorageData));
```

**main.js**

```js
    const moment = require('moment');
    let data;
    const today = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');

    /* Below code snippet will find the columnPosition of the desired column in a table */
    const columnPosition = $(`#RecordIdMain`)
        .find(`th:has(a:contains("Record"))`)
        .index();

    if (value === 'localStorage') {
    // how can I call the localStorageData object and parse the recordId or autoId or simId and assign the value to data ? 
      data = ???
    } else if (value === 'date') {
        data = today;
    } else {
        data = value;
    }
```

Comment: keep in mind, localStorage is just saving a string. you are just saving a string to localStorage, and then reading a string back. whatever you do with that string beyond that, has nothing to do with localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Using a localStorage object requires you to JSON.parse() it first.

```js
console.log({'loginStatus': JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loginStatus')).isAuthenticated})
```

You need a variable that contains the item key you want to retrieve, and it has to be a string:

```js
const key = 'someId' || 'autoId' ... // (some logic to determine the item key)

let data

fakeLocalStorageItem = { 
  "autoId": "123",
  "simId": "aaa111",
  "someId": "2bb2bcQQQ",
  "recordId": "44342asd33423-234234"
}

// Convert fake json to imitate localStorage string format:
const stringJson = JSON.stringify(fakeLocalStorageItem)

// Convert it back to a js object
storedItem = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(stringJson))

if ((1 + 1) === 2) {
  data = storedItem.key
} else if (value === 'date') {
  data = today;
} else {
  data = value;
}
```

Comment: value is a variable that has "localStorage" string ...in my situation I have to add an if case like that....

Comment: No, I have stored the localtorage is as an object and the object have recordId or autoId, or simId or sessionId...so I would like to have way to get any one of the items to be retreived and assign into the data varaible.. so .i can't just say ```window.localStorage.getItem('recordId ')``` ...so this will always get recordId only ..so if    the value stored simId or autoId the above will not work right ?